# What's the difference between a Control Unit and a Microcontroller/Sequencer?

Tags: architecture, controller, microcontroller, hardware, processor

As I understand them:

Microcontroller/Sequencer is a circuit that intakes OPcode from Instruction Register (combines it with timing data from Timing Register, decodes that in the decode ROM) and then sends signals all other processor's components through the control bus that dictade them what to do (e.g. Enable Writing on B register).

My guess is that Control Unit is the combination of all that: Microcontroller, Instruction register, Timing Register, decode ROM and the control bus. Is that so?

Comment: these terms are too generic to get that kind of detail.  what is your source so that we can maybe interpret that specific use of these terms.  there is no universal definition and wont be so it is all relative.

Comment: @old_timer I know these terms by myself, different sources describe their functions differently. It makes sense now that you said they don't have a universal definition, you might be right. I just never understood the difference between a Control Unit, a Microcontroller and a Sequencer. I was hoping to get maybe some good descriptions of each, since Wikipedia's writing style is too hard for me and I couldn't find answer to my question elsewhere. Sorry for unnecessary long answer.

Comment: a microcontroller should be the obvious one, essentially some form of cpu core, with on board ram and non-volatile storage for the firmware/software (flash/eeprom some sort of rom) plus some number of basic perihperals usually gpio, timers and some others.   a generic chip level product that can be used for many things.

Comment: the other terms taken alone could mean just about anything, I could see a rack size or building sized sequencer likewise a control unit.  at the same time deep within an mcu are at least one bus interface between the cpu and other items and perhaps more and sometimes those are called memory controller units, is that a control unit?

Comment: a lot of the time the definition is whatever the author wrote, so if marketing at company A writes we have some new embedded blah.  thats their definition of embedded from that person or department at that company.  Engineering at same company for same product might not call it embedded.  Company B might have a technical manual that uses the word embedded and the context may feel or be different than company A's marketing materials.   this is how the world works and there is no way to fix it nor reason to.

Comment: @old_timer, Thank you for your answers, I now understand that these terms are basically synonyms.